# jquery resizable stops me editing my div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make an editable div resizable. I've managed to make the div editable. I've managed to make the div resizable. I've now realised it is no longer editable.

A little trial and error shows this is due to the resizable library doing something I don't understand. If I use the element inspector I can see that the type I type is stored in the HTML, but it's never visible.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("a");
$(ele).resizable();
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true">This is without JQuery and works great but doesn't resize.</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="a"></div>
```

Can some one explain what I need to do so I can edit my div?

Oddly, if I code content into the DIV (such as `myElement.innerText = "hello world"`) then it is editable, until I delete all the code and then it appears non-editable again

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2rk0pny3/2/) to demonstrate it

Comment: Just FYI your JS code can just be `$('#a').resizable()`

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, I appreciate that. I've shown it this way, because it's how I'm using it in the "real" code :) Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this codw

```
<div contenteditable="true" >This is without JQuery and works great.
</div>
<div id="a">
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" contenteditable="true">  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, so make the div which is resizable a wrapper?

Comment: Yes, wrapper is the resizable div